# Android ICS accessibility square activation code

Tags: android, accessibility, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-source

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Boz3yVBz1hM#t=18s
In this video, at 22 sec, man is drawing a square on SetupWizard screen of Samsung Nexus.
Could anyone please help me to find the source code which handles this gesture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for that specific application isn't part of AOSP, but you can use [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to detect arbitrary shape gestures.